# Incorrect HelpMaker file display from a Swing project

Tags: java, swing, applet, chm

I created a HelpMaker project and I want to be able to post that from a Java Swing button.  This will allow it to display:

```
try {    
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20, 60);    
    ta.read(new FileReader("wsc-desktop.chm"), null);    
    ta.setEditable(false);    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Button, new JScrollPane(ta));    
}    catch (IOException ioe) {    
    ioe.printStackTrace();    
}
```

But this is not successful, because it is not a 'text area.'  It is a helpmaker project. A .chm file.

This is generally what appears in the 'text area.'

```
/Name.html Ý ‡X /opensearch.html ýc‰
 /operations.html �†n‰ 
/Package.html ävˆ( /payload-specification.html Ëb‰0
/Port.html õPˆ  /SecurityFramework.html Õ
Etc…
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to display this correctly?

Comment: First, find a (custom) Java component that can display CHM..  No class in the JSE is able to parse/display CHM.

Answer (score 0):

CHM is not a good choice for Java. You can try JavaHelp (Java native), OracleHelp (Oracle's implementation of JavaHelp) or WebHelp (HTML + javascript) formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
File chmDirectory = new File("<The destination of the file>");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.directory(dhmDirectory);
pb.command("cmd", "/c", "wsc-desktop.chm");
    try {
        pb.start();
    }  catch (IOExcecption e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

// This works, but I do not know how to make the destination of the file dynamic.
```